# How to get the data from the HTML user input to a python file

Tags: python, html

I've been trying to get the data from an HTML file to a Python file, here is the HTML code.
I tried CGI but I don't think it works for me. I don't know what to do or what to try.

```
<form class="login100-form validate-form" action="../backenddeneme/main.py" method="post">
                    <span class="login100-form-title">
                        User Login
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Username is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-12">
                        <span class="txt1">
                            Forgot
                        </span>
                        <a class="txt2" href="#">
                            Username / Password?
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-136"></div>
                </form>
```

I tried this python code but when I click the submit button, a blank white page with my python code appears

```
import sqlite3
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
username = form.getvalue("username")
password = form.getvalue("password")

conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='%s' AND password='%s'" % (username, password))
result = c.fetchall()
print(result)
conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What code have you tried so far for the data extraction? Please add it to the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using BeautifulSoup
Look here - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-web-scraping-python-beautiful-soup/
To download it -
`pip install bs4`

Comment: As I know bs4 is used to get HTML data from a website, I need the input data from my website. I don't think I can use bs4 because of that.

Answer (score 0):

try this
 `<form class="login100-form validate-form" action="/<function name>" method="post">`
and on the server side use request.form.get method to get the username or password

Comment: There isn't any server side for me, I'm working on this project and I run it on a python HTTP server

Comment: Sorry I was assuming you were using Flask framework

Comment: How can I use that Flask framework and is it good? Because I think I can't run a python file in my localhost because of python's http.server does not support SQL

Comment: Flask is great, You can run it in your local host, you can try flask development server to connect SQL database too. you have to install Flask and read their official doccs to use it